# react-google-maps change marker icon to waypoints

Tags: reactjs, laravel, google-maps, react-google-maps

I am developing tracking web view of delivery app using react-google-maps (https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/). I need to customize the icon of the waypoints marker. I already search in google and integrate to my codes but unfortunately none worked. Data are from api response.

Here's my code.

```
 const TrackingMap = compose(
        withProps({
            googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
            loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
            containerElement: <div style={{ height: '700px', width:'100%' }} />,
            mapElement: <div style={{ height: '100%' }} />,
        }),
        withScriptjs,
        withGoogleMap,
        lifecycle({
            componentDidMount() {
                let destinationLat, destinationLng, pickupLat, pickupLng;
                var waypts = [];
                var wayptsMarker = [];
                const DirectionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

                for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                    if (i < points.length-1 ) {
                       waypts.push({
                            location: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(points[i].destination_latutude), parseFloat(points[i].destination_longitude)),
                            stopover: true,
                        });
                    }
                    
                    if (i == 0) {
                        pickupLat = parseFloat(points[i].pickup_latutude)
                        pickupLng = parseFloat(points[i].pickup_longitude)
                    }
                    
                    if (i == points.length-1) {
                        destinationLat = parseFloat(points[i].destination_latutude);
                        destinationLng =  parseFloat(points[i].destination_longitude);
                    }
                }

                DirectionsService.route({
                    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(bookingDetails.rider_latitude), parseFloat(bookingDetails.rider_longitude)),
                    destination:  new google.maps.LatLng(destinationLat, destinationLng),
                    waypoints: waypts,
                    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                    optimizeWaypoints: true,
                }, (result, status) => {
                    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        this.setState({
                            directions: result,
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    )(props =>
        <GoogleMap
            defaultZoom={7}
            defaultCenter={{ lat: parseFloat(bookingDetails.rider_latitude), lng: parseFloat(bookingDetails.rider_longitude) }}
        >
            
        {props.directions && 
            <DirectionsRenderer
                suppressMarkers= {true}
                directions={props.directions}
                geodesic={true}
                options={{
                    polylineOptions: {
                        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                        strokeColor: '#F36629',
                        strokeWeight: 6,
                    },
                }}
            />
        }

        </GoogleMap>
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using `suppressMarkers` in your DirectionsRenderer object but to properly use it, you need to put it inside the `options` property. Setting it to true removes all the default markers(origin, waypoints and destination). You can then use `Marker` object to put markers on these positions. Since Waypoints is in array, you can loop through this array using `.map` and put a Marker object with `icon` property. This will change and set all your Waypoints marker with the icon value.

Here's a code snippet:

```
<GoogleMap
        defaultCenter={{ lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 }}
        defaultZoom={13}
      >
        {this.state.directions != null && (
          <DirectionsRenderer
            directions={this.state.directions}
            options={{ suppressMarkers: true }}
          />
        )}
        <Marker position={this.state.origin} />
        <Marker position={this.state.dest} />
        {this.state.waypts.map(waypt => (
          <Marker
            position={{ lat: waypt.location.lat, lng: waypt.location.lng }}
            icon={'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/blu-blank.png'}
            label={'W'}
          />
        ))}
      </GoogleMap>
```

Here's a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/directions-hjqwp6?file=index.js). Put your API key in the `index.js` file for the code to work.